# Candle Grbl only says port opened

Tags: 20.10

I have a problem with my Candle CNC host. I run it as root, and it only says Port opened.

[image: Candle CNC host running]

It seems that it doesn't have any other way. I chose the correct USB port, baud rate, and others.

Here is my `neofetch` output:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.10 x86_64  
Host: Swift SF114-32 V1.12  
Kernel: 5.8.0-26-generic  
Uptime: 3 days, 15 hours, 2 mins  
Packages: 2764 (dpkg), 16 (snap)  
Shell: bash 5.0.17  
Resolution: 1920x1080  
DE: GNOME  
WM: Mutter  
WM Theme: Adwaita  
Theme: Layan-dark [GTK2/3]  
Icons: Tela-blue-dark [GTK2/3]  
Terminal: gnome-terminal  
CPU: Intel Pentium Silver N5000 (4)  
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 605  
Memory: 2808MiB / 3735MiB
```

The solution is that I changed the baud rate.

Comment: Please do not put your answer in your question.  You can write your own answer below then in 2 days accept it as the correct answer.  I do recommend that you write details of what you did to solve your issue.  It may help someone else if they have the same issue as you.  Thank you!

Comment: Okay! I will do that!

Comment: But i have answer ban

Comment: When you edit your question, below you will see a check box labeled "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style"  Select that and write your own answer.  Remove the SOLVED from the title.

Comment: which Baud rate you choose?, for dafaut it works 115200? which value you choose

Comment: @Jay's3DChannel Are you still banned? If not, please add your solution as an answer. Also don't forget to remove "SOLVED" from the title. Thanks!

Comment: Yes i am still banned